# How do I include the source maps of NPM dependencies in the compiled bundle?

Tags: webpack, babeljs, source-maps

Let's say I have a frontend app compiled with Babel and Webpack to a bundle, which includes a source map of the code I own. However, if I'm looking for a problem in association with third-party dependencies, I would only see their minified code in the browser debugger, since that's what is downloaded from NPM and available on disk. I could only reformat this code automatically, but never see the original code as it was written.

Is there any way to configure the development environment to provide source maps of the dependencies' code in addition to source maps of my code?

Answer (score 2):

Try using https://github.com/webpack-contrib/source-map-loader

> This loader is especially useful when using 3rd-party libraries having their own source maps. If not extracted and processed into the source map of the webpack bundle, browsers may misinterpret source map data. source-map-loader allows webpack to maintain source map data continuity across libraries so ease of debugging is preserved.